# Duplicate a sheet based on a number input into a cell

Tags: vba, excel, button

I've got a workbook that I fill in every time I commission a certain type electrical system.

Each workbook contains 6 Sheets that are filled in and used every time (Site information etc.). There are two sheets that I manually duplicate anywhere between 2 times and 40 times depending on the requirement, and fill in specific information for each 'Electrical Panel'.

The amount of times they are duplicated is a value I input on the leading information "Sheet".

Is there a simple way to create a button/macro (that doesn't print) that will duplicate the Sheet and name it in a fashion like such:

PANEL # of X

(Where # is the current number, and X is the total)

My skills sadly lie in Electricity, not Excel, or Visual Basic Script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it is asked that an effort be made to try this yourself first and we help when you get stuck, as you're a sparky and probably not in the market for learning too much programming I'll get you going, though normally you would have to try it yourself first.

Do as follows and it should get you started:

1. With Excel open press Alt + F11 (this opens the VBE Editor)
2. Select Insert -> Module
3. Paste in the below code and make changes where there are [Square Brackets] - I have put an example below for each one
4. Next to where you are going to enter the number of panels insert a shape; whatever shape you want to click on
5. Right click on the shape and Assign Macro. Select the MakeSheets from the list and click Ok
6. Right click the shape again, go to Size and Properties > Properties and uncheck Print Object

Now when you enter a number in the cell and click it should create the sheets. If it hits an error it will give you a message telling you what it is, though this may not mean a lot to you. Hopefully it will work fine anyway.

The code to paste in:

```
Sub MakeSheets()
On Error GoTo Err_handle

Dim i As Integer, i2 As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet

' Set the worksheet to copy
Set sh = Worksheets("[Name of sheet to copy]")
' Example: Set sh = Worksheets("Panel 1 of 1")

' Get the number of sheets to copy
i = Worksheets("[Name of Sheet Where You Enter the Number]"). _
    Range("[Cell reference]")
' Example: i = Worksheets("Panel Summary").Range("C3")

' Say how you want to name the first sheet
sh.Name = "Panel 1 of " & i

i2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For x = 1 To i - 1
    sh.Copy After:=Sheets(i2 + x - 1)
    ' Say how you want to name subsequent sheets
    Sheets(x + i2).Name = "Panel " & x + 1 & " of " & i
Next x


Err_handle:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf _
    & "Error Desc: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

End Sub
```

Comment: I was stuck as soon as i opened the VB window! Thanks a lot for you help with this, it works perfectly !